# Cassandra java driver warning

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I keep seeing this message in the logs, mainly everytime the query is made.

> Query SELECT username AS col6,gender AS col1,last_name AS col2,email
>   AS col3,first_name AS col4,something_uuid AS col5,group_email AS
>   col7,deleted AS col8,puars AS col9 FROM something_data WHERE
>   username=?; is not prepared on /XX.YY.91.205:9042, preparing before
>   retrying executing. Seeing this message a few times is fine, but
>   seeing it a lot may be source of performance problems.

The query is made using a mapper.get("username") ---> com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper

That's how I initialize the mapper in the constructor. After that I don't use the mappingManager anymore.

```
this.mapper = mappingManager.mapper(MyPojo.class);
```

Any clues why?

Comment: Can you put a piece of code that creates `MappingManager` & `Mapper` instances? I suspect that you don't keep `MappingManager` after its creation

Comment: @AlexOtt I've added that. Your assumption is correct. After initialisation in the constructor, the MappingManager is not used anymore.

Comment: In constructor of what? Of request or something else? My question is - are you recreating Mapping manager very often? Like for every get operation?

Comment: We were creating the MappingManager with @Bean from spring, but it had a custom name which was not used in repositories. In Repository it was initialised by spring using IoC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you aren't keeping the instance of the `MappingManager` for a long time, but recreate it every time you fetch the data. It's a big mistake - `MappingManager` should have the same life time as `Cluster` and `Session` objects.

The mapping manager is responsible for extracting the field annotations from your class, generating queries, preparing them & then executing. The prepared queries are cached inside mapping manager, so when it destroyed, the cache is lost, and when you trying to perform `get` again, the process is repeated, leading to significant overhead - query need to be prepared again, and this is significant network overhead, so actually your queries are slower than if you used non-prepared queries.

Just move `MappingManager` instance to some static block, so it could be reused for all your mapper operations.

Comment: @BadChanneler @Alex Ott @undefined_variable, I have initialized the MappingManager as a static variable. But still I am getting this warning sometimes. `{Cluster cluster; Session session; static MappingManger mappingManager; public void init(){mappingManager = new MappingManager(session)}; public Pojo get(primaryKey){Mapper<Pojo> mapper = mappingManager.mapper(Pojo.class); return mapper.get(primaryKey);}}`

Comment: it's very hard to reason without seeing the code & error. Create a new question for it